# Call a script within a view PYTHON / DJANGO

Tags: python, django, import, python-import

I'm very new in Python and Django or the code in general

I created a view that get value from an html template with javascript. With these values collected i want to run a script that consider these new values

```
@csrf_exempt
def register(request):
      type_list=request.POST.get('selected_type').split("&") #array collected from checkboxes
      from_date=request.POST.get('start_date').replace("&","") #date collected
      to_date=request.POST.get('end_date').replace("&","") #date collected
      import transaction.query #script I want to run
      profiling = transactionprofiling.objects.all() #database/model updated with the script
      tmpl = loader.get_template("transaction/index.html")
      cont = {'profiling': profiling}
      return HttpResponse(tmpl.render(cont)) #return the model in the template
```

The definition doesn't work as it doesn't save the value "type_list" "from_date" "to_date"
I made some research but nothing shows up

thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where did you actually _save_ the object? and what's inside the `transaction.query`? Is there any errors showing up?

Comment: the transactionprofiling is saved into a model, and the others are only on the variables for now, I tried to save them into a model as well but nothing seems to be saved.

Comment: `code code filterdate.start_date=from_date
      filterdate.end_date=to_date
      filterdate().save() `

Comment: into the query I update the table/model called "transactionprofiling" with an SQL query and everything seems to work when I declare random variable within query.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone is interested about the answer I found, I created new models and saved the result within the models, then run the script by using these models and not the variables ! cheers !

```
@csrf_exempt
def register(request):
      type_list=request.POST.get('selected_type').split("&")
      from_date=request.POST.get('start_date').replace("&","")
      to_date=request.POST.get('end_date').replace("&","")

      filtertype.objects.all().delete()

      n = 0
      for item in type_list:
            n = n + 1
            print(item)
            add = filtertype(id=n, transaction_type=item)
            add.save()

      filterdate.objects.all().delete()

      add = filterdate(id=3, start_date=from_date,end_date=to_date)
      add.save()

      print(type_list,from_date,to_date)

      import transaction.query

      profiling = transactionprofiling.objects.all()
      tmpl = loader.get_template("transaction/index.html")
      cont = {'profiling': profiling}
      return HttpResponse(tmpl.render(cont))
```